# Solving a system of non-linear equations to find relationship between arguments

Tags: python, nonlinear-equations

I have a program that implements a multivariate function, call it $f = \mathcal{Q}(Z,v)$ that I can compute given $Z,v$. The $v$ variable is related to the $f$ variable by another relation, call it $v = \mathcal{L}(f)$ (so given $f$ I have a program that can compute $v$). I would like to use this to obtain how $v$ varies with $Z$.

My present approach is to evaluate $\mathcal{L}(f)$ for a bunch of $f$, and store the $v$ against $f$. Then, I would input different values of $Z$ (held constant) and $v$ to compute $f$, and compare these $f$ and $v$ with those from the earlier evaluation. The closest pair would be selected and I have my $v$ for a certain $Z$.

Is there a better way than this ad hoc method? I use Python, so using any associated libraries to solve the task is allowed.

Comment: If you recast this as a nonlinear system $f - \mathcal{Q}(Z,\mathcal{L}(f)) = 0$, then this is a pretty standard numerical continuation problem and you can just look at $v$ evaluated along this $f$ curve

Comment: Are $v,Z,f$ all scalars, or what are their dimensions?

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks! Apologies if it was obvious, I've never heard of this method. Could you suggest any up to date Python tools for computing these level sets? Most of what I could find (pycont, pacopy) are outdated and are no longer supported.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth $v,f$ are vectors in 3D, Z is a scalar.

Comment: I think there are a few Python packages out there purpose-built for continuation but for simple problems it's pretty easy to build your own tool around an existing nonlinear solver using, e.g., arc length continuation

Comment: Can you state the dimensions of $v$ and $f$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth physical dimensions are $v$ is velocity and $f$ is force